# Get Branch Name in Bamboo Deployment Plan

Tags: bamboo

How can I get the branch name in a script for a deployment plan in bamboo? The variables listed in the documentation show that we can use `bamboo.repository.branch.name`, but that doesn't seem to work in a deployment plan.

Answer (score 18):

It works for me do It like this:

It's `bamboo.planRepository.branchName` not `bamboo.repository.branch.name`

[image: Configuration]

And it will output this in the log:

[image: Log1]
[image: Log2]

I'm using bamboo 5.7, and if it doesn't work, it's probably because of [this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12900).